# Webkit iOS issue HTTP post in WebView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, web, ipad, webkit

I have a login page. On giving the authenticated credentials , I show a home page in which I have a button. On click of that button I need to open a web page within the app, I did it using WEBkit. This page takes user to SalesForce login page. I wanted to open the page which comes after login page within the webpage because the credentials are same as entered through app in the beginning. I did this using HTTP post request but it is not working as expected. Could anyone help in providing the correct steps.
Please find the below code:

```
    var webView: WKWebView!
     let url = "https://...."
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

            var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    let params = ["username":   LoginDetails.current.userName!,
                   "password":  LoginDetails.current.password!,
                   "vhost": "standard"
          ]
    
    let postString = self.getPostString(params: params)
    urlRequest.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    webView.load(urlRequest)
    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    }
    
    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
    func getPostString(params:[String:String]) -> String
        {
            var data = [String]()
            for(key, value) in params
            {
                data.append(key + "=\(value)")
                
            }
            return data.map { String($0) }.joined(separator: "&")
        }
```

Comment: To provide correct steps we need to see how this is correctly done in Web (i.e. when you logged in to SalesForce, how the request that navigates you to home page look like). Note that also it's possible that SalesForce actively prevents such injection. You probably need to contact their support to figure out.

Comment: Please clean up your code example and keep it to the minimum. That helps others to focus on your question. Thanks.

Comment: @NicoS. I have cleaned up the code. Hope this is more readable